# lldb: cannot cast from type 'std::__1::shared_ptr<Pkt>' to pointer type 'Pkt1*'

Tags: c++, lldb

I'm debugging a program (segfault) using LLDB on MacOS Big Sur. I have these types:

```cpp
class Pkt {
  public:
    std::uint8_t header;
    Pkt(std::uint8_t header): header(header) {
    }
};
class Pkt1 : public Pkt {
  public:
    static inline const std::uint8_t headerVal = 0x01;
    static inline bool matchHeader(std::uint8_t byte) {
      return (byte == headerVal);
    }
    Pkt1(std::uint8_t header): Pkt(header) {}
};
class Pkt2 : public Pkt {
  public:
    static inline const std::uint8_t headerVal = 0x02;
    static inline bool matchHeader(std::uint8_t byte) {
      return (byte == headerVal);
    }

    uint32_t pkt2Var;
    Pkt2(std::uint8_t header): Pkt(header) { pkt2Var = 33; }
};
class PktGen {
  private:
  public:
    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<Pkt>> pkts;
    void genPkt(uint8_t header) {
      if(Pkt1::matchHeader(header)) {
        pkts.push(std::make_shared<Pkt1>(header));
      }
      if(Pkt2::matchHeader(header)) {
        pkts.push(std::make_shared<Pkt2>(header));
      }
    }

    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<Pkt>> getPkts() {
      std::queue<std::shared_ptr<Pkt>> tmp;
      tmp = pkts;
      while(!pkts.empty()) {
        pkts.pop();
      }
      return tmp;
    }
};
```

There's probably something wrong with my getPkts() function, though it works here: https://godbolt.org/z/h8Y4qPKnh.
Anyway, my question is with LLDB: if I want to access:

```
p std::static_pointer_cast<std::shared_ptr<Pkt1>>(pkts.front())->pkt2Var
```

I get:

```
error: <user expression 42>:1:6: no template named 'static_pointer_cast' in namespace 'std'
```

How do I go about casting smart pointers in LLDB?

Answer (score 1):

`std::static_pointer_cast` requires `#include <memory>`.

But in any case, your use of `std::static_pointer_cast` is just plain wrong anyway.

DON'T specify `shared_ptr` itself in the template parameter, only the pointer type being casted to, eg:

```
p std::static_pointer_cast<Pkt1>(pkts.front())->pkt2Var
```

However, `Pkt1` does not have any `pkt2Var` member, but `Pkt2` does:

```
p std::static_pointer_cast<Pkt2>(pkts.front())->pkt2Var
```

If the debugger still won't accept `static_pointer_cast`, then just use an ordinary `static_cast` instead (since you don't need the debugger taking shared ownership anyway):

```
p static_cast<Pkt2*>(pkts.front().get())->pkt2Var
```